# AppleScript not working as expected when mounting smb-shares with provided users

Tags: applescript, keychain, smb, finder, nas

I just wrote that little script to mount some of my smb-folders of my NAS.

```
mount volume "smb://TimeMachineUser@NAS/TimeMachine"
mount volume "smb://anotheruser@10.0.99.99/Folder"
```

But every time I execute this script AND TimeMachine is UNmounted, I get this message from Finder that I don't have the required access-permissions to access this server. (I could provide the German version of this error if desired...) TimeMachine gets mounted tough with its correct permissions (TimeMachineUser).

If TimeMachine is already mounted and I execute the script again, it does mount "Folder" (with access as expected)

Some additional information about the setup:

- TimeMachineUser has a quota to limit the backups made to the NAS.
- NAS = 10.0.99.99 (just the hostname to trick the keychain where my passwords for both users are saved).
- anotheruser actually has access to "Folder"

My assumption would be something like Finder is using TimeMachineUser instead of anotheruser for the second share - but why should it and does it really?

While executing with unmounted TimeMachine and getting that said error, here is the "answers-log" of Apple Script Editor:

```
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "smb://TimeMachineUser@NAS/TimeMachine"
        --> error number -10004
end tell
tell application "Script Editor"
    mount volume "smb://TimeMachineUser@NAS/TimeMachine"
        --> file "TimeMachine:"
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "smb://anotheruser@10.0.99.99/Folder"
        --> error number -10004
end tell
tell application "Script Editor"
    mount volume "smb://anotheruser@10.0.99.99/Folder"
        --> error number -5014
end tell
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem bypassed:
The TimeMachine-Volume actually doesn't have to be mounted (TM mounts it automatically when trying to make a backup). So now I only have to mount my shares via 1 user.

But nevertheless it is a really weird behaviour...